# Calculating how much a subgroup affect the general mean

Tags: statistics

Given `N` observations with a mean of `M1`, I'm looking for a way to calculate whether `M2` = the mean of the same group excluding `K` observations significantly differs from `M1`. 
`H0: M1 = M2` 
`H1: M1 != M2`

For example: The mean grade of 200 students is 91. I want to find out whether a specific subgroup, say 10 students, significantly affect the mean (in other words, if I were to exclude those 10 students, would the mean differ significantly?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible and you can create a simple formula for it. Everyone knows to calculate mean `M1` you take the sum of `N` observations and divide by `N`. Alternatively, if you want to find the sum of the observations, take `M1` and multiply by `N`. Using this idea we can measure how removing a subgroup from a group will affect the mean. Let's define these variables:

`M1` = Original group mean

`N1` = Number of "people" in original group

`S1` = Sum of values of original group

`M2` = Subgroup mean

`N2` = Number of "people" in subgroup

`S2` = Sum of values of subgroup

If we exclude the subgroup from the group, our new group sum will be (`S1`-`S2`). Then to find the mean of this new group we divide by the new number of "people", which is now (`N1` - `N2`). Doing this will give you your new group mean. Also note as I said earlier, you can calculate the sum by multiplying the mean by the number of "people".

TLDR, use this formula:
$$\frac{(M1*N1)-(M2*N2)}{N1-N2}$$

Hope this helps, also sorry if the formatting is poor, I'm brand new to the site.

Edit:
As a quick example, let's say you have a group of 200 students with a mean test score of 91. You want to remove the bottom 5% (10 students) who have a mean score of 48. Using the formula above, the new mean is calculated like this:

$$\frac{(91*200)-(48*10)}{200-10} = 93.263$$

Notice that this intuitively makes sense, if you cut out the worst 10 scores you'd expect the mean to increase by a bit, although not much since it's just 5% of scores.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you show here is how to calculate the mean with and without the subgroup, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to find out whether the two means significantly differ from each other.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by telling if they significantly differ. Do you mean the difference in means? If so then just take the absolute value of the difference in the mean, that is: $\vert M1-M2 \vert$. This would tell you how far apart the means are. Like in my example $\vert 91-93.263 \vert = 2.263$ so 2.263 is how far apart the means are, or how much they differ. If this isn't what you are looking for I'd need more details, perhaps in the form of a problem?

Comment: @Stars Perhaps you meant you want to tell if taking away a subgroup will affect the mean at all? Unless the means are exactly equal, taking away the subgroup will always affect the mean. Even if the mean is 91 and you take away a subgroup with a mean of 90.9, the new mean will not equal 91 (it'd be something like 91.01, but that depends on the size of the two groups).